# Recorrer los datos de una lista de elementos con distintas clases en HTML con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, chrome, nodos

soy algo nuevo en esto y queria consultarles como puedo hacer para entrar en los datos especificos de cada uno de los nodos de "ulhistoricocompleto" donde todos los nodos tienen distintas clases y dentro de las mismas otros dos elementos que siempre se repiten que son "hstInf" y "hstTtl" que a su ves tienen otra subclase dentro que es donde debo entrar.

Yo logro entrar a la lista de nodos del ulHistoricoCompleto pero no logro recorrer su listado...Estaba intentando lo siguiente pero no me funciona.

```
let elementsHistoric = document.getElementById("ulhistoricocompleto");

for (var element of elementsHistoric) {
                let title = element.querySelectorAll("#ulhistoricocompleto .hstLne")[0].querySelector(".hstTtl").innerText;
                let date = element.querySelectorAll("#ulhistoricocompleto .hstLne")[0].querySelector(".hstDta").innerText;
                let description = element.querySelectorAll("#ulhistoricocompleto .hstLne")[0].querySelector(".hstMais").innerText;
                data.push({ title, date, description });
            }
```

Si alguien me podria dar una mano, estaria totalmente agradecido!
Todo esto es con el objetivo de sacar una informacion mediante WebScraping de una pagina Web para el analisis de sus datos.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes resolverlo de la siguiente manera:
seleccionas #ulhistoricocompleto luego recorres todos los elementos en `children` y en cada uno, seleccionas los elementos de las clases que mencionas, así:

```
document.querySelector("#ulhistoricocompleto").children.forEach(element => {
    let title = element.querySelector(".hstLne").textContent;
    let date = element.querySelector(".hstDta").textContent;
    let description = element.querySelector(".hstMais").textContent;
    data.push({ title, date, description });
});
```

Te recomendaría que usaras la función String.trim() para cada uno de los valores y así eliminas los espacios de formato de código.